# the point $f(x+h)$ and the first principles

Tags: derivatives

If a value is added to the argument inside the parenthesis of a function, the point moves to the left on the $x$-axis.

e.g. if $y = f(x)$, and $f(x) = x^2 - 2$, then $f(2) = 2$, so the point on the graph would be $(2,2)$

and if $y$ is changed to $y = f(x+2)$, the point on the graph would be $(0,2)$, which is moved to the left on the horizontal axis by two units.

So why when differentiating the same graph $y = x^2 - 2$, using first principles, is the co-ordinate $f(x+h)$ moved up the $y$-axis as though the point was $f(x) + h$ and not to the left along the $x$-axis by $h$ units?

Comment: What do you mean $\;f(2)=(2,2)\;$ ?? Are you talking of a function $\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2\;$ ? I don't think so...

Comment: I don't think the point moves to the left on the horizontal axis when 2 is added...

Comment: "If a value is added inside the bracket of a function" ????

Comment: $(2,0)$ is a point on the $x$-axis of the $x-y$-plane. $(2+ h,0)$ is another point on the $x$-axis to the right of the first one.

Comment: Btw, if $f(x)$ is a function in $x$ and $f(2)=(2,2)$ then $f(x+2)=(x+2,2)$...so when $x=2$ how is it $0$?

Comment: The point $(2,f(2))$ is a point in the cartesian plane. The point $(2+h, f(2+h))$ is another point.

Comment: In conclusion, we have points $(x,y)$ in the cartesian plane, When "plotting" the graph of a *function* $f$ we have to use the points $(x,f(x))$. When $x$ is "moved to" $x+h$ the point on the graph moves from $(x,f(x))$ to $(x+h, f(x+h))$. That's all.

Comment: @Sean If $f$ is continuous at $x$ (which it must be to be differentiable) then $h$ doesn't have to be positive. $h$ can approach zero from below. Also $f(x+h)$ is not necessarily $\geq f(x)$. If the derivative at $x$ is negative then for a small enough positive $h$: $f(x+h) < f(x)$